# How do you access rule tag information in a server side component

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

If I retrieve a rule with

`Rule rule = ruleFinder.findByKey(issue.ruleKey());`

Then both `getTags` and `getSystemTags` returns empty arrays in all circumstances.

Is there a way to work round this bug and read tags in a server side component?

Comment: From which server extension point do you need to access rule tags ?

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource A MeasureComputer